# Apollo server 4 with or without express : standaloneServer vs expressMiddleware

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am new to graphql and I would like to build my first API, using mongoose and MongoDB.
So far, I've built some API's using Express, mongoose and MongoDB (in MERN apps).

I'd like to use **Apollo/server** , and I realise there are two options to build a server, using `startStandaloneServer` , therefore not using express (i mean, not installing it as dependency), and using `expressMiddleware` , building what it seems like a more traditional express app (as I understand it).

I've managed to build two severs, one with each, connect them to my DB, and do some basic queries (no mutations for now), so far so good.

But before continuing and start building more complex queries, mutations, authorization strategies with JWT tokens, etc.. , I'd like to ask what are the differences between the two "ways" of using **ApolloServer** , pros and cons or things I should take into consideration.

Comment: I did! I found that it was reasonably well explained in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in Apollo Server documentation.
[here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/standalone/) and [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/express-middleware/).

The function `startStandaloneServer` is an Apollo's quick setup of an express app, to get started in a quicker way.
That means we need less setup to configure our server, but at the same time is less configurable: e.g. we cannot configure our own `cors` policy.

The function `expressMiddleware` would allow us a more typical configuration of our server, including the middleware we decide to use.

`startStandaloneServer` uses `expressMiddleware` under the hood.